# Docker push Linux image from tar on Windows

Tags: docker

I have a Linux Docker image saved in a tar-file (from `docker save`) produced on a Linux host. Is it possible to push that image on a Windows host to a remote repository? When I try to load it, it fails with unsupported OS.

I came across https://github.com/Razikus/dockerregistrypusher which claims to do what I want but it doesn't work for me.

Is there a way I can get Docker to ignore the OS-check? Or tell it to directly upload from the tar file without loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked into the library and figured out what was going on and why it wasn't working. I've created a PR for a fix but since the author hasn't responded yet and I needed it now, I had to fork it and publish myself. It can be found here https://pypi.org/project/dockertarpush/ if anyone is interested.